# Convert mac path to posix in python

Tags: python, macos, path

I'm stuck trying to convert a Mac Path to a POSIX path in Python. I want to convert something like this:

```
'Main HD:Users:sasha:Documents:SomeText.txt'
```

to this:

```
'/Users/sasha/Documents/SomeText.txt'
```

I know I could simply split the string into a list and then rejoin it with the correct separator. But I believe there must be a much more elegant solution I'm missing, possibly involving the "macpath" or "os.path" python modules. However, I've not been able to figure out a function within these modules that will do the trick of converting between the two formats.

An additional problem of the simple string manipulation solution is that if I have multiple HDs, then a simple solution won't work. For instance:

If you have a path like:

```
'Extra HD:SomeFolder:SomeOtherText.txt'
```

we would want that to be converted to:

```
'/Volumes/Extra HD/SomeFolder/SomeOtherText.txt'
```

Not to:

```
'/SomeFolder/SomeOtherText.txt'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does path like 'Main HD:Users:sasha:Documents:SomeText.txt' come from? I'm using OSX Mavericks but never see that before

Comment: It's the pre-OS-X way of specifying directory paths. The hard-disk name comes first, with a leading `:` indicating a relative path.

Comment: How are you getting this path? Applescript?

Comment: @number5 I'm trying to script through the MegaSeg (audio player) Database file, which has this format for the paths of the songs.

Comment: Split the string then `os.path.join` is better way to go, you could have already done it if not asking it here :) But thanks for letting me know the ancient OS 9 format with `:` as path separator.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done as an interim solution, however, the problem is that if you have a path like:

    'Extra HD:SomeFolder:SomeOtherText.txt'

I would want that to be converted to:

    '/Volumes/Extra HD/SomeFolder/SomeOtherText.txt'

Comment: The additional information seems to be availaibe via, `diskutil` to match device nodes to volume names, and `mount` to match device nodes to mount points.  given a volume name, find which device holds it via `diskutil list` or some such, then find the mount-point of that volume via `mount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Pythons `subprocess` module for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def asExec(ascript):

    osa = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'],
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return osa.communicate(ascript)[0]

def asConv(astr):

    astr = astr.replace('"', '" & quote & "')
    return '"{}"'.format(astr)

def aScript(aspath):

    ascript = '''
    set posixPath to POSIX path of {0}
    '''.format(asConv(aspath))
    return ascript

aliasPath = "Main HD:Users:sasha:Documents:SomeText.txt"
print(asExec(aScript(aliasPath)))
```

**Result:**

> /Main HD/Users/sasha/Documents/SomeText.txt

Comment: This works properly for me IF the volume name is actually a mounted volume. That is, "Macintosh HD:some:path" -> "/some/path", "Other Volume:some:path" -> "/Volumes/Other Volume/some/path". But it fails if the volume doesn't exist, as in "Nonexistent Volume:some:path" -> "/Nonexistent Volume/some/path".

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I can use anything (eg.`aliasPath = "foo:bar:baz"`) and it returns `/foo/bar/baz`, so it's unclear why it would fail for you.

Comment: @l'L'l: /foo/bar/baz is not a correct translation -- it should be either /bar/baz (if "foo" is the startup disk) or /Volumes/foo/bar/baz (otherwise).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Translating `foo:bar:baz` to `/foo/bar/baz`, `/bar/baz`, or even `/Volumes/foo/bar/baz/` makes no difference — if it's a non-existent `HFS` path it won't be translated as a valid path would. If the scenario called for a global find/replace (disregarding the paths validity) then regex might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any methods in the standard library.  `os.path` provides path manipulation methods for the current os and there are not methods to convert path style or change separators. The specific os path manipulation modules such as `macpath`, `posixpath`, and `ntpath` do not contain methods to convert path separator symbols and the like. (Source: [os.path docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html))

As such, I think replacing the separator with string manipulation is a reasonable solution for this problem.